# Using range to show all Elements of Table

Tags: html, templates, go, web

i want to execute a template with following data:

```
type EquipmentPage struct {
    Name string
    EquipmentList [] model.Equipment
    Pages [] Page

}
```

On my Template File i want to loop through all Equipment Elements in my Database Table.

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID int
    Name string
    Description string
    ImgPath string
    Category string
    Availability bool
    Amount string
    Storage string
}
```

My Template File looks like this:

```
{{define "base"}}

{{range .EquipmentList}}


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-5">
     <p> {{.Name}} </p>
     <br>
     {{.Description}}
     <br>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-main btn-margin" ><b>Ausleihen</b></button> 
     {{if .Availability}}
     <em class="status-text" style="color:green"> verfügbar </em>
     {{else}}
     <em class="status-text"> entliehen </em>
     {{end}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2" style="margin-top: 30px">
     <img class="float-right img-responsive bild" src="{{.Imagelink}}" alt="Kann nicht gezeigt werden">
  </div>
  </div>

{{end}}
```

{{end}}

When i run my programm it just shows me the first Entry of my Table.

I want to display all entrys. 
I have the contents of the equipment array in the console output and there are all items displayed.

EDIT:

Controller: (Template Test has no content)

```
func Equipment(w    http.ResponseWriter,    r   *http.Request)  {   
data := EquipmentPage{ 
    Name: "Equipment",
    EquipmentList: model.GetEquipment(model.Db),
    Pages: []Page{
        {
            Title: "Meine Geräte", 
            Active: false,
            Link: "/my-equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Equipment", 
            Active: true,
            Link: "/equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Logout",
            Active: false,
            Link: "/index",
        },
    }, 
}


fmt.Println(model.GetEquipment(model.Db))


        tmpl:= template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/base_equipment.html", "template/test.html"))
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)


}
```

ModeL:

```
func GetEquipment(Db *sql.DB) []Equipment {
    sql_readall := `
    select ID, Name, Description, ImgPath, Category, Availability, Amount, Storage from Equipment
    `

    rows, err := Db.Query(sql_readall)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
    defer rows.Close()

    var result []Equipment
    for rows.Next() {
        equipment := Equipment{}
        err2 := rows.Scan(&equipment.ID, &equipment.Name, &equipment.Description, &equipment.ImgPath, &equipment.Category, &equipment.Availability, &equipment.Amount, &equipment.Storage)
        if err2 != nil { panic(err2) }
        result = append(result, equipment)
    }


    return result
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is mostly correct, the only problem is that there is no `ImageLink` field nor method declared in the example, that kind of mistake will break the rendering of the template, but you already know that because you're checking the error returned from `Execute/ExecuteTemplate` right? So assuming that in your real code `ImageLink` method exists or you just mistyped `ImgPath`, then your code is ok, therefore the problem is in the part of the code that you haven't shared. (https://play.golang.org/p/SRa24adIeMk)

Comment: What part of my code you want me to share?

Comment: That which is broken. Which part that is I do not know since I haven't seen it. But let's start with the one that closest to the problem. Where you call Execute/ExecuteTemplate on the template.Template instance and pass the page data and also that part which retrieves that data. Also if this is a nested template then do show the parent template, and it's parent and so on.

Comment: Added Controller and Model to my Post

Comment: When you check the error from ExecuteTemplate what does it say?

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: `err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data); fmt.Println("error=", err)`.

Comment: change ImageLink to ImgPath, now it works. *facepalm* my fault.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: As a best practice, always print the returned error whenever there's a problem with any funcion call! It'll save everyone's time.

Comment: im very fresh to this, but thanks for the advice